# I can't find out why my Autohotkey script sometimes works and sometimes not

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I have the following script:

```
gosub, menucreate
Settimer, CheckRun, 1000

ExitSub:
        ExitApp
return

Mess:
        msgbox tada
return

menucreate:
Menu, TRAY, DeleteAll
Menu, TRAY, NoStandard
Menu, TRAY, Add, Exit , ExitSub
Menu, TRAY, Add, Message , Mess
return

CheckRun:
        gosub ,menucreate
return
```

On occasions the menu Message works, but sometimes not.

Every few starts of this program it shows the message, and it keeps working if I reload.

But if I restart it might not working (or might ... I couldn't figure out any pattern)

Comment: Is it because the window doesn't have focus? http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlFocus.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in mean time I found out, but till now hadn't time to add this here (and kinda forgot).

The thing is: If the menu gets redrawn every second it will only cause an action until it gets redrawn.
So if you have pulled it up and the redraw happens before you click on a item nothing happens.

This thing here was just a test script to find out why the actual one has stopped working.
In that one I have included a test if actually something has changed and only then the menu get redrawn ... and voila it works.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you fail to end the Auto-execute section.

> After the script has been loaded, it begins executing at the top line, continuing until a Return, Exit, hotkey/hotstring label, or the physical end of the script is encountered (whichever comes first). This top portion of the script is referred to as the auto-execute section.

So try and put a return after your settimer and see if that helps